# At a loss for syntax on TVF

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I for the life of me cant seem to see the syntactic error near the BEGIN statement of my User Defined Table Valued function. Can someone please tell me what I am missing here...

Every single time I've modified the syntax I am always coming back to the same issue.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION F_I_SO_M2M_SOHEXFILT ()
RETURNS TABLE (
    fsono VARCHAR(256)
    ,fcustno VARCHAR(256)
    ,fcompany VARCHAR(256)
    ,fcity VARCHAR(256)
    ,fcustpono VARCHAR(256)
    ,fackdate VARCHAR(256)
    ,fcanc_dt VARCHAR(256)
    ,fccurid VARCHAR(256)
    ,fcfactor VARCHAR(256)
    ,fcfname VARCHAR(256)
    ,fcfromno VARCHAR(256)
    ,fcfromtype VARCHAR(256)
    ,fcontact VARCHAR(256)
    ,fclos_dt VARCHAR(256)
    ,fcountry VARCHAR(256)
    ,fcusrchr1 VARCHAR(256)
    ,fcusrchr2 VARCHAR(256)
    ,fcusrchr3 VARCHAR(256)
    ,fdcurdate VARCHAR(256)
    ,fdisrate VARCHAR(256)
    ,fdistno VARCHAR(256)
    ,fduedate VARCHAR(256)
    ,fduplicate VARCHAR(256)
    ,fdusrdate1 VARCHAR(256)
    ,festimator VARCHAR(256)
    ,ffax VARCHAR(256)
    ,ffob VARCHAR(256)
    ,fnextenum VARCHAR(256)
    ,fnextinum VARCHAR(256)
    ,fnusrqty1 VARCHAR(256)
    ,fnusrcur1 VARCHAR(256)
    ,forderdate VARCHAR(256)
    ,fordername VARCHAR(256)
    ,fordrevdt VARCHAR(256)
    ,fpaytype VARCHAR(256)
    ,fphone VARCHAR(256)
    ,fprint_dt VARCHAR(256)
    ,fprinted VARCHAR(256)
    ,fsalcompct VARCHAR(256)
    ,fsalecom VARCHAR(256)
    ,fshipvia VARCHAR(256)
    ,fshptoaddr VARCHAR(256)
    ,fsocoord VARCHAR(256)
    ,fsoldaddr VARCHAR(256)
    ,fsoldby VARCHAR(256)
    ,fsorev VARCHAR(256)
    ,fstate VARCHAR(256)
    ,fstatus VARCHAR(256)
    ,ftaxcode VARCHAR(256)
    ,ftaxrate VARCHAR(256)
    ,fterm VARCHAR(256)
    ,fterr VARCHAR(256)
    ,fzip VARCHAR(256)
    ,flprofprtd VARCHAR(256)
    ,flprofrqd VARCHAR(256)
    ,fndpstrcvd VARCHAR(256)
    ,fndpstrqd VARCHAR(256)
    ,fdeurodate VARCHAR(256)
    ,feurofctr VARCHAR(256)
    ,fsalescode VARCHAR(256)
    ,fusercode VARCHAR(256)
    ,fncancchrge VARCHAR(256)
    ,flchgpnd VARCHAR(256)
    ,fllasteco VARCHAR(256)
    ,timestamp_column VARCHAR(256)
    ,identity_column VARCHAR(256)
    ,fackmemo VARCHAR(256)
    ,fmstreet VARCHAR(256)
    ,fmusrmemo1 VARCHAR(256)
    ,fndbrmod VARCHAR(256)
    ,fccontkey VARCHAR(256)
    ,flcontract VARCHAR(256)
    ,fccommcode VARCHAR(256)
    ,fpriority VARCHAR(256)
    ,ContractNu VARCHAR(256)
    ,fbilladdr VARCHAR(256)
    ,OpportunNum VARCHAR(256)
    ,CreatedDate VARCHAR(256)
    ,ModifiedDate VARCHAR(256)
    ,OppCrType VARCHAR(256)
    ,QuoteNumber VARCHAR(256)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @intFlag INT = 1
    DECLARE @findtable TABLE (
        dechexval VARCHAR(max)
        ,Occupied BIT
        ,hexval NVARCHAR(max)
        )

    WHILE (@intFlag <= 65535)
    BEGIN
        --PRINT @intFlag
        INSERT INTO @findtable
        SELECT @intFlag
            ,''
            ,right(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(cast(cast(min(@intFlag) AS INT) AS VARBINARY(8))), 4)
        SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
    END;
    --select * from @findtable
    SELECT som.*
    FROM m2mdata01.dbo.somast AS som
    INNER JOIN @findtable AS ft ON ft.hexval = right(som.fsono, 4)
    RETURN
END
GO
```

I'm pretty much at a loss, I have several other UDF's that follow the same syntax, but for whatever reason, I cant get this one correct.

Comment: Please shorten the SQL to be respectful of our time. And add details about the error message. What and where.

Comment: Ouch. What you have here is a multi line table valued function. This by itself will often perform far worse than a scalar function or even most loops. Add to that the fact that this then has a while loop and a call to a scalar function and you have a recipe for disaster. You could rewrite this as a single select statement and it would perform far better. Also, you should list your columns in your final select statement instead of select *. If you do this as a single select you don't have to define the return table either.

Comment: With all due respect, I know how to write a UDF and a TVF. This is a forest through the trees issue. If I shorten the code, I have defeated the purpose. And the specific error code is "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BEGIN'."

Comment: Sean, that gives me an idea.. There is an easier way to do this... Thanks!

Comment: It isn't really a forest through the trees. It is that you posted a question with an issue and I suggested that your approach is painfully slow. I also suggested a way to improve it. Then finally I posted code for how you could improve it. It isn't about shortening the code, it is about making sql that is accurate and fast.

Comment: @SeanLange I think that the first comment by op was directed to usr, not you

Comment: @Lamak I think you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your function to something more like this. This will be a LOT faster than looping inside here.

```
CREATE FUNCTION F_I_SO_M2M_SOHEXFILT ()
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    E6(N) as (select 1 from E4, E1), --100,000 rows
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E6
    ),
    FindTable as
    (
        select N as IntFlag
            , '' as Occupied
            , RIGHT(master.dbo.Fn_varbintohexstr(Cast(Cast(Min(N) AS INT) AS VARBINARY(8))), 4)
        from cteTally
        where N <= 65535
    )

    SELECT fsono,
    fcustno,
    fcompany ,
    fcity,
    fcustpono,
    fackdate ,
    fcanc_dt ,
    fccurid,
    fcfactor ,
    fcfname,
    fcfromno ,
    fcfromtype ,
    fcontact ,
    fclos_dt ,
    fcountry ,
    fcusrchr1,
    fcusrchr2,
    fcusrchr3,
    fdcurdate,
    fdisrate ,
    fdistno,
    fduedate ,
    fduplicate ,
    fdusrdate1 ,
    festimator ,
    ffax ,
    ffob ,
    fnextenum,
    fnextinum,
    fnusrqty1,
    fnusrcur1,
    forderdate ,
    fordername ,
    fordrevdt,
    fpaytype ,
    fphone ,
    fprint_dt,
    fprinted ,
    fsalcompct ,
    fsalecom ,
    fshipvia ,
    fshptoaddr ,
    fsocoord ,
    fsoldaddr,
    fsoldby,
    fsorev ,
    fstate ,
    fstatus,
    ftaxcode ,
    ftaxrate ,
    fterm,
    fterr,
    fzip ,
    flprofprtd ,
    flprofrqd,
    fndpstrcvd ,
    fndpstrqd,
    fdeurodate ,
    feurofctr,
    fsalescode ,
    fusercode,
    fncancchrge,
    flchgpnd ,
    fllasteco,
    timestamp_column ,
    identity_column,
    fackmemo ,
    fmstreet ,
    fmusrmemo1 ,
    fndbrmod ,
    fccontkey,
    flcontract ,
    fccommcode ,
    fpriority,
    ContractNu ,
    fbilladdr,
    OpportunNum,
    CreatedDate,
    ModifiedDate ,
    OppCrType,
    QuoteNumber
    FROM   m2mdata01.dbo.somast AS som
    INNER JOIN FindTable AS ft ON ft.hexval = RIGHT(som.fsono, 4)
```

Comment: This is a great answer too. Im just now starting to get comfortable with CTE's but no doubt this will perform much better.

Comment: Because the table variable was static (and because I was using it in another UDF) I went ahead and made it a real table and because I didn't need to use variables anymore, I wrote the final statement as a view. After I get things firmed up on my over all process, I will schema bind it and create it as an indexed view for better performance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your table a name in the declaration

```
CREATE FUNCTION F_I_SO_M2M_SOHEXFILT ()
RETURNS @t TABLE (
....
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: This type of table function should be avoided because the performance is horrible for multi statement table functions.

Comment: Whether the function is poorly performing is irrelevant as we don't know the usage context.  The immediate problem is the syntax error as noted above.

Comment: Yes it doesn't solve the issue at hand. However it painfully obvious that it is a multiline table valued function with a while loop inside. Why not help the OP to get a better solution instead of just answering the question?

Comment: The fact that the same function can be refactored to be an inline table valued one, which **will** perform better is absolutely relevant